# Finding the root vectors of a given Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

*This problem is from 'Lie Algebras in Particle Physics' by Howard Georgi.*

> Consider the simple Lie algebra formed by the ten matrices:
> $$\sigma_a, \sigma_a\tau_1, \sigma_a\tau_3, \tau_2$$
> Where for $a= 1,2,3$ where $\sigma_a$ and $\tau_a$ are Pauli matrices (we write $\sigma_a\tau_b$ for $\sigma_a\otimes\tau_b$). Take $H_1 = \sigma_3$ and $H_2 = \sigma_3\tau_3$ as the Cartan subalgebra. Find the weights of the adjoint representation.

I know the dimension of the adjoint representation is equal to the number of independent generators which is 10, so writing down the adjoint representation explicitly is not realistic. How do I solve this problem? Do we have an easy approach to general Lie groups?

Edit: we use $\sigma_a$ for $\sigma_a\otimes I$ and $\tau_a$ for $I\otimes\tau_a$.

Comment: I'm not super sure what your definitions here mean. How do all the things in your list fit in the same Lie algebra. The middle two seem to be tensor/outer products of the matrices and so live in a different vector space to the matrices, no? This may be a physics notational convention but I don't follow. I do however know that the Lie algebra is supposed to be $\mathfrak{so}_5$ given it is simple, we know its dimension and the dimension of  a Cartan subalgebra. So you can find out it's root system that way.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail please?

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/678522/2451

Comment: Even with the edit you have made there is still a problem. What is the Lie bracket on such a space? As to my other point I am just referring to the classification of simple Lie algebras. There are, up to isomorphism, 3 simple Lie algebras with rank 2 (i.e. dimension of any Cartan subalgebra, also equal to the number of nodes in the Dynkin diagram) and only one of these has dimension 10. So it must be $\mathfrak{so}_5 = \mathfrak{sp}_4$.